# How to tar zip directories which are 7 days older

Tags: directory, date, gzip

I have a folder that contains a lot of xml files stored in it, the folder name has a format 'yyyymmdd' eg., 20180515. I wanted a script that can zip the folder of this kind, when the folder grows 7 days older.
Actual path : /test/xml_files/yyyymmdd/*.xml.

Comment: If any of the answers solved your problem, please [accept it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking the checkmark next to it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Given the date format of the directories, you could use a simple shell script that computes the cutoff date then loops through all of the directories in question and asks whether they are older (less than) the cutoff date.

```
#!/bin/sh

cutoff=$(date -d "7 days ago"  +%Y%m%d)
for d in [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]
do
  if [ $d -lt $cutoff ] && [ ! -f "${d}".zip ]
  then
    zip -r "$d" "$d"
  fi
done
```

The only requirement is a date utility (such as the one from GNU) that can compute an arbitrary date.

The script will only attempt to zip directories that are older than the cutoff and that do not already have a corresponding zip file. You could substitute `tar` and gzip if you prefer; just be sure to adjust the `-f` condition.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you have only directories with date name in the given path.
And you want date comparing with directory name and not the modification or creation date .

Code

```
offset_date=$(date -d "-7 day" +%s) ; for i in $(ls -1) ; do if [ $(date -d $i +%s ) -gt $offset_date ] ; then echo $i ; fi  ; done | xargs tar -czf directories.tar
```

Explanation :
Here I am saving epoch date older than 7 days in offset_date variable and comparing it to directory name after converting directory name to epoch.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using find command:

```
find  /test/xml_files/ -type d -ctime +7 -exec tar -czvf {}.tar.gz {} \;
```

- `find /test/xml_files`: here `/test/xml_files` is the location where we want to search
- `-type d`: we need to find only directories (file type)
- `-ctime +7`:  only consider the ones with modification time older than 7 days
- `-exec tar -czvf {}.tar.gz {} \;`: This basically executes `tar -czvf` on the results found by find.

```
tar -czvf <output-tar-name> <input-folder-name>
```

- `c` for creation of tar
- `z` for compressing in gz
- `v` for verbose
- `f` for files

So basically if find gets two results: `20180501` and `20180502`.
It will pass then in `{}` and create two archive tar files:
`20180501.tar.gz` and `20180502.tar.gz`